# PHP socket_write() sends just a part of data

Tags: php, sockets

I need to send a big amount of data with a single shot. But socket_write sends only a part of it. The function and the $buffer variable are correct:

```
socket_write($socket, $buffer, strlen($buffer));
```

Maybe it is possible to customize the limit of buffer or something?

There are many solutions on this issue at [http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-write.php](http://php.net) but they all separating buffer to send it part by part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try setting the send buffer size using the SO_SNDBUF option. This would allow the buffer at TCP layer to hold more data.

$sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)
socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, 5000);

You can see the current value of the socket buffer using the socket_get_option:
var_dump(socket_get_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF));

URL: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php