# foreach loop breaking before reaching end of loop

Tags: php, sockets, foreach

I have an interesting problem that I can't get to the bottom of.

My code is as follows:

```
public function __destruct()
{
    foreach ($this->_queue as $index => $header) {
        $result = socket_write($this->_socket, $header);
        if (!$result)
        {
            $s_err = socket_last_error($this->_socket);
            $str_err = socket_strerror($s_err);
        }
    }
    socket_close($this->_socket);
}
```

This is used to track events on google analytics. An event always consists of 3 different header strings that I need to write to the socket.

I have been testing with 2 events, meaning that `$this->_queue` contains 6 strings.

Every single time I run through the code however, I only ever reach index `[2]` (The third item) and then the loop ends, the `socket_close($this->_socket);` line is never ever reached.

I have tried the solutions found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558802/php-socket-write-works-first-time-but) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373715/php-socket-write-sends-just-a-part-of-data) with no success, I set the buffer size to 100000 and included a usleep(5), as well as the appropriate carriage return characters.

Is there any other reason that my code could possibly be quitting the foreach before it's done?

Is there another, *better* way to do this?

Comment: Any info in browser console? Isn't the socket waiting for you to read an answer betwen writes?

Comment: @SergioBernardo `socket_write` just returns an integer that will tell me how many bytes have been written, or `false` if there was an error. I have debugged with xdebug and it's written successfully every time, I also have not found anything on php manual or elsewhere that would indicate that it was waiting for anything to be read. This works for the first 3 separate items in the queue, and then breaks out of not just the loop, but the function as well after the third item.

Comment: In such a case I would replace the foreach(...) for something like: for($i=0; $i < sizeof($this->_queue); $i++) { $header = $this->_queue[$i]; ... Then place print("loop $i - somewhere\n") in specific places to see where it stops...

Comment: Thanks Sergio, I'll try that. If it works I will let you know to create an answer so that I can mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

First, i notice the socket closes after the for-loop is existed, and for that to happen, all operations in the loop will have to complete. 
Secondly, the problem could be with the result for item[2] which keeps the function hanging because the:
if (!$result){
    $s_err = socket_last_error($this->_socket);
    $str_err = socket_strerror($s_err);
  }
may not be returning the error captured.. check the two error functions being called. thus,socket_last_error($this->_socket) and socket_strerror($s_err).

Use "continue" in the if block to jump any error that may be causing the problem... thus:
if (!$result){
    continue;
  }

this will jump any error and proceed to the next item in the loop..
if that works, then the problem will definitely be with the two error functions being called

Comment: The problem here is that every time I test, the first 3 items are different slightly, because I create them differently. I have debugged the problem multiple times with xdebug and have not had any errors returned (`$result` has never been false), so the 2 error functions are never actually called, which is why I'm having so much trouble figuring out what is going wrong :)

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... 6 strings, and you're retrieving 2 strings at a time (`$index` and `$header`)  If the `$index` values are numbered from *zero,* and the last one you see is *two,* then the loop has run **(0..1..2) = 3** times which is exactly the right number: **2 * 3 = 6.**

But, in general, the easiest way to debug these things is to temporarily add a `print` statement or two, so that you can *see* what's going on.

With PHP, you must always check the logs for "warnings," because the language is notorious for "keeping going" in situations where it ought to stop cold.

Comment: No, I think you're either misunderstanding the question or have had a slight hiccup when envisioning the array - 6 strings in the array means that it the `$index` variable will go from 0 - 5, not 0 - 2.. I have checked for warnings and for return values from the socket_write function that would indicate that the write itself failed. I posted here as a last resort, not because this was some easy issue that could be solved with simple PHP debugging tips. Sorry if this sounded too harsh, but your answer should be a comment, not an answer, it's not very helpful either.